# Classes in Linked List not working

Tags: python, class, linked-list

Got a schoolwork to do showroom with 2 classes: Car & Node, while Node data contain Car class with its data. Then I have to make a Linked list, should be doubly, but I think a simple should work as well, with Nodes containing Cars. The only function in Linked list is inserting a new Node with new Car. It should be sorted by price of cars upwardly.

Tried this, but it keeps telling me

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, id = None, name = None, brand = None, price = None, active = None):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.brand = brand
        self.price = price
        self.active = active

class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.next = None
        self.data = Car()

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = Node(None)

    def insertNode(self, car):
        newNode = Node(car)
        curNode = self.head
        if self.head.data is None:
            self.head = newNode
        if newNode.data.price < curNode.data.price:
            newNode.next = curNode
            self.head = newNode
        else:
            while curNode.next is not None and curNode.next.data.price <= newNode.data.price:
                curNode = curNode.next
            newNode.next = curNode.next
            curNode.next = newNode
db = LinkedList()

def init(cars):
    for car in cars:
        db.insertNode(car)

def add(car):
    db.insertNode(car)
```

Did I miss something, 'cause I think it should be working.

Comment: What exactly should the node do and what is "data" for? You hand the Node init the variable data but you assign only an empty Car every time you create a node.

Comment: @Banana of course, that than I have more functions where I define that **car** and I call the function, but it still keeps telling me the same error.

Comment: I'll edit it with followings

Comment: I'm just not sure about the role of node. But one problem is the line: if newNode.data.price < curNode.data.price:
The way you wrote it, the newnode might contain a car with an int value but the current might still be one that has the value set to None. Those cant be compared

Comment: I think you want to indent your second if;else statement.

Comment: That's why I have that **if** for self.head first, so that if there's no self.head than I insert newNode as self.head and than in list, ther can't be a Node with no data.

Comment: Nodes are elements of Linked list

Comment: The way you wrote it, those are two separate if statements. If you don't indent the second one, its not part of your first ifs body and will be executed anyways.

Comment: Let me get this straight. 
You want a class for Cars.
You want a class for nodes that basically connect two cars.
You want a class LinkedList whose object contains information about **all** cars ordered in price.

True or something wrong here?

Comment: There's a Car class with objects (cars), class Node, and every Node has in its data their own car (object of Car) and Linked list makes a list of Nodes.

Answer (score 0):

In `Node.__init__` you have the line `self.data = Car()` which creates a `Car` instance using the default values (which are all `None`). That means that the price of every `Car` in the list is `None`. Later, you are getting an exception when you try comparing prices with `newNode.data.price < curNode.data.price` because you can't compare `None` values.

You probably need to replace `self.data = Car()` with something else. It's not obvious to me from your current code where the car data is supposed to come from or what format it is in. If the `cars` sequence you're iterating over in the top level `init` function is a list of `Car` instances already, then you should probably just do `self.data = data` in `Node.__init__`. Otherwise you'll need to do something else to extract the car data and pass it to the `Car` constructor. You may also want to consider getting rid of the default arguments to `Car.__init__`, since it doesn't seem to make much sense to create a car without them.

Comment: Yeah but if **self.head is None** than you add a newNode(car) with eg. _car = (1, 'car', 'bmw', 3000, True)_

Comment: Than I should have _self.head = Node(car)_ right?
Because that's how it should work right? 
Than I have **self.head** and after that i can start comparing new Nodes with self.head (which is Node) as it contains data (car) specifically _id, name, brand, price & active_

Answer (score 0):

I see several problems, mainly regarding type consistency, in your code. You should maybe rethink what exactly the class structure here is supposed to do, how to set the default values etc. Also: Do you want to have the nodes next variable to be another node?

Assuming the following: We have Cars. Each Car has a Name, Brand and pricetag. We want two cars to be connected by a Node. And we want lists that can hold nodes and allow us to insert a new Node. Insertion should happen such that the node hierarchy connects cars in ascending price value. Two neighboring nodes share one car. You could write this as something like:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, name = " ", brand = " ", price = 0):
        self.name = name
        self.brand = brand
        self.price = price

class Node:
    def __init__(self,car1,car2):
        assert type(car1) == type(car2) == Car
        if car1.price > car2.price:
            self.next = car1
            self.current = car2
        else:
            self.next = car2
            self.current = car1

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self,firstnode):
        self.ListOfNodes = [firstnode]

    def insertNode(self, car):
        for i in range(0,len(self.ListOfNodes)):
            curnod = self.ListOfNodes[i]
            newnod = Node(car,car)
            if  car.price < curnod.current.price: 
                if i<len(self.ListOfNodes): #If its not the last node
                    newnod.next = curnod.current
                if i>0: #If its not the first node, i.e. it has a predecessor
                    ListOfNodes[i-1].next = newnod.current
                self.ListOfNodes.insert(i,newnod)
                return
            elif car.price < curnod.next.price: 
                newnod.current = curnod.current
                curnod.current = car 
                self.ListOfNodes.insert(i,newnod)
                return
        newnod.current = self.ListOfNodes[-1].next #this is only reached if the price is higher than all before
        self.ListOfNodes.append(newnod)




car1 = Car(name = "baby",brand= "honda", price = 1000)
car2 = Car(name = "yomomma",brand= "Benz", price = 10)
car3 = Car(name = "PussyWagon",brand= "Dodge", price = 100)
car4 = Car(name = "FakeTaxi",brand= "HellNah", price = 10000000)
car5 = Car(name = "LondonTaxi",brand= "ChumBucket", price = 1)
p = Node(car2,car1)
lst = LinkedList(p)
lst.insertNode(car3)
lst.insertNode(car4)
lst.insertNode(car5)
```

It's very generic but it should work.